# How do I get an apache tomcat server running on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have just downloaded eclipse and I am trying to run an application I made at work. I need to set up the working environment to the one I have at work which includes an apache tomcat server. I downloaded apache tomcat 8.0 and unzipped the file but I don't know how to get the Apache tomcat to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Open Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Installed Runtimes to create a Tomcat installed runtime
Please make sure you downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
check following link for details
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all download Apache Tomcat Server as Zip file from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi. Then unzip and save at some location(Remember the location).

Goto
    Eclipse->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments->Add
    Popup will come, choose version of Apache Tomcat Server that you have downloaded
    Click on Next. Enter the some name of the server(This will appear in servers view),
    Enter the location of the server and then click on finish.

Now
    Goto Window->Show View->search for servers and click on OK.

Now
     Now choose the servers view. The server added by you will appear there. Now double click
     on that server, it will open the configuration settings menu.

Make sure you have selected "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)" and
also change the HTTP/1.1 Port Number from default 8080 to something else(8081 for e.g.) if you 
have any other software using that port.
And then save it
Now right click on the server and then click on start.

That's it you have successfully configured Apache Tomcat. You should get Tomcat's welcome page
when you go and visit "localhost:8081/" in your web browser.

Comment: Your link is for Tomcat 6.  Perhaps 8, or even just 7, might be a more useful link.  This link might be quite good: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @Paul Hicks Yes you are right. I posted it quickly.